# Retrofit list of items always null

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I'm trying to get a list of items from a WS on my android app, but the response is always null.

This is my code, and I can't figure it out:

Interface:

```
public interface CategoriesInterface {

   @GET("/categories")
   List<CategorieModel> getCategories(@Query("k") String token);
}
```

AsynkTask:

```
    new AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create();

            RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint( "WS_URL" ) // The base API endpoint.
                    .setConverter( new GsonConverter(gson) )
                    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                    .build();

            CategoriesInterface categoriesInterface = restAdapter.create( CategoriesInterface.class );

            List<CategorieModel> list = categoriesInterface.getCategories( params[0] );

            // LIST IS ALWAYS NULL

        } catch (RetrofitError error) {
            Log.e("ERROR", error.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

}.execute( token );
```

Model:

```
public class CategorieModel {

   @SerializedName("id")
   private String id;

   @SerializedName("cat_pt")
   private String cat_pt;

   @SerializedName("cat_es")
   private String cat_es;
}
```

Response JSON format:

```
 "categories": [
    {
        "id": "2",
        "cat_pt": “STRING",
        "cat_es": “STRING"
    },
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong. The response List is always null.

Thank you

Comment: What do you get when you actually go to that url in a browser? Is there data? Is "WS_URL" the correct url?

Comment: The URL was correct, Christopher response bellow worked fine. Thank you any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON returns a CategoryContainer, which contains an array of CategorieModel. Add a new model class:

```
public class CategorieContainer {
    private List<CategorieModel> categories = new ArrayList<>();
    // TODO Getter / Setter
}
```

and change your Retrofit-Interface:

```
@GET("/categories")
CategorieContainer getCategories(@Query("k") String token);
```